# in relation to web development, what is a taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy

Can people explain what taxonomy means in terms of a web site?

My current understanding it a classification of the contents in relationship to each other, but it seems like it must go beyond that simplistic definition.  and yes, I have read the wikipedia entry for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taxonomy tends to refer to a main navigational hierarchy - Stack Overflow's taxonomy for example would be the "Questions", "Tags", "Users", "Badges", and "Unanswered" links at the top of the page.

Taxonomy can mean many things though but for a website it tends to refer to the navigational hierarchy and organization of the site.

Answer (score 3):

a way to categorize your content.  One content could exist in multiple taxonomy categories.  For example, Ronald Reagon could exist in the following categories: Presidents, Actors.  You could have a site with content about Ronald Reagan.  You could have category filters.  Taxonomy would allow you to show the Reagan content for each category without having to duplicate the content.